# Codename One: How to put a line break in a build hint?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to extend my info.plist by

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> 
<string> first line
second line</string>
```

but I don't know how to apply this to the respective build hint (`ios.plistInject`). Note: the line break is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

That particular build hint can be added using the `ios.NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`  (See [the advanced topics section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) of the developer guide and do a find for "UsageDescription").

In general, if you copy and paste a build hint into Codename One Settings that includes line breaks, the line breaks will be retained.

Comment: You can also edit `codenameone_settings.properties` and add a `\` newline at the end of the line

Comment: thanks for the "the advanced topics section" hint. But the line break seems not to get copied anyways. Or maybe NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription does not support line breaks at all?